# Python Pandas: Iteratively create new column with value from a different row within group of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Using Python/Pandas I am trying to transform a dataframe by creating two new columns (`A` and `B`) conditional on  values from different lines (from column `ID3`), but from within the same group (as determined by `ID1`).

For each `ID1` group, I want to take the `ID2` value where `ID3` is equal to `31` and put this value in a new column called `A` conditional on `ID3` being a `1` or a `2`. Similarly, I want to take the `ID2` value where `ID3` is equal to `41` and put this value in a new column called `B`, again conditional on `ID3` being a `1` or a `2`.

Assuming I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID1': (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 'ID2': (151, 152, 153, 154, 261, 262, 263), 'ID3': (1, 2, 31, 41, 1, 2, 41), 'ID4': (2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2)})
print(df)

     ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4
0    1   151    1    2
1    1   152    2    2
2    1   153   31    1
3    1   154   41    2
4    2   261    1    1
5    2   262    2    1
6    2   263   41    2
```

Post-transformation format should look like what is shown below. Where columns `A` and `B` are populated with values from `ID2`, conditional on values within `ID3`.

```
    ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4    A    B
0    1   151    1    2    153  154
1    1   152    2    2    153  154
2    1   153   31    1   
3    1   154   41    2
4    2   261    1    1
5    2   262    2    1         263
6    2   263   41    2         263
```

I have attempted using what is shown below, but transform will retain the same number of values as the original dataset. This poses a problem for the lines in which `ID3` = `31` or `41`. Also, it returns the `ID2` value by default if there is no `ID2` value of `31` within the group.

```
df['A'] = df.groupby('ID1')['ID2'].transform(lambda x: x.loc[df['ID3'] == 31])
df['B'] = df.groupby('ID1')['ID2'].transform(lambda x: x.loc[df['ID3'] == 41])
```

Result:

```
   ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4   A   B
0    1   151    1    2  153  154
1    1   152    2    2  153  154
2    1   153   31    1  153  154
3    1   154   41    2  153  154
4    2   261    1    1  261  263
5    2   262    2    1  262  263
6    2   263   41    2  263  263
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In no why do I think this is the best solution, but it its a solution.

You can replace `.loc` with `.where`, which will return `NaN` wherever the condition is not true. Then backfill `NaN`, and then again filter with `.where` on `ID3` being 1 or 2

```
df['A'] = df.groupby('ID1')['ID2'].transform(lambda x: 
       x.where(df.ID3==31).fillna(method='bfill').where(df.ID3.isin([1,2])))

df['B'] = df.groupby('ID1')['ID2'].transform(lambda x: 
       x.where(df.ID3==41).fillna(method='bfill').where(df.ID3.isin([1,2])))

   ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4      A      B
0    1  151    1    2  153.0  154.0
1    1  152    2    2  153.0  154.0
2    1  153   31    1    NaN    NaN
3    1  154   41    2    NaN    NaN
4    2  261    1    1    NaN  263.0
5    2  262    2    1    NaN  263.0
6    2  263   41    2    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: This works well! Thank you for the helpful feedback. The code does require that my dataframe be sorted on `ID1` and then `ID3` for the backfill to not replace all values with `NaN`. Many thanks!